# Responsive website text alignment issue

Tags: css, size, screen, padding, resolution

I'm totally new to web development. I have created a single paged website on my preview server which can be seen at
(Lin Removed)

The text padding is not setting up properly in all screen sizes. How to set it up so that it becomes responsive.

Fiddle with the whole code is at http://jsfiddle.net

The CSS code for the taste page is

```
html {
height: 100%;
}
body
{
margin:0;
padding:0;  
background-image:url('../images/bgs/bg.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
margin: 0;
background-size:contain;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position:relative;
bottom:0px;
top:0px;
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
max-height:100%;
max-width:100%;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/bgs/bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/bgs/bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
font-family:Trebuchet MS, Arial, 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
font-size:1em;
}
.header
{
background-color:#212528;
}
.taste
{
background-image:url('../images/bgs/bg2.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
margin: 0;
background-size:contain;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position:relative;
bottom:0px;
top:0px;
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
-webkit-background-size: contain;
-moz-background-size: contain;
-o-background-size: contain;
background-size: contain;
max-height:100%;
max-width:100%;
background-position:center;
}
.taste-div
{
padding-left:26em; 
width:18.750em;
text-align:justify;
padding-top:1.7em;
padding-bottom:9em;
display:block;  
color:#000;
font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
}

@font-face {
font-family: "Bebas";
src: url("../fonts/BebasNeue.eot") format("eot"),
url("../fonts/BebasNeue.woff") format("woff"),
url("../fonts/BebasNeue.ttf") format("truetype");
}

.banner {
background-color: #2a2f33;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
padding-top:1%;
}
.title {
font-size: 110%;
font-weight: bold;
font-family:'Bebas';
display:block;
}
.title a {
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;   
}
.header {
background-color: #2a2f33;
padding: 10px;
}
.nav{
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
text-align:center;
font-family:'Bebas';
font-size:1.9em;
}
.nav li{
display:inline;
color:#fff;
}
.nav a{
display:inline-block;
padding-left:0.4em;
padding-right:0.4em;
}
.nav hover{
color:#cc8568;
}
```

and the html is

```
<div class="taste-div">
Everyone is loving the sweet taste, easy drinking wines packed with flavour,  fruitiness and fun.</td>
<p><h3>sweet! White 75cl</h3>
<strong>Description!</strong> Sweet peach and apricot fruit flavours with a hint of lychee and tangy citrus. Ripe, fruity and very refreshing. <br />
<strong>Origin!</strong> Western Cape, South Africa<br />
<strong>Grape variety!</strong> Blend of Chenin Blanc, Semillon and Muscat d’Alexandrie<br />
<strong>Alcohol!</strong> 12% by volume</p>
sweet! Red 75cl
Description! Sweet red and black berry flavours with a hint of tropical fruit and mocha spice. Smooth, easy-drinking and moreish. Origin! Western Cape, South Africa
Grape variety! Blend of Merlot, Pinotage and Muscat d’Alexandrie
Alcohol! 13.5% by volume
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, your problem is since you are working in responsive design, you have to make padding and margin in percentage and not px or em.

Please look at your style.css file and change the padding-left from 26em to 40%.
and use media queries if needed.

Comment: Thanx alot for the quick responce bro. I already have use media querries but when I use it in % it automatically pushes the text towards left or right on different screen sizes. Thats the main issue Im facing.

Comment: Yes it is bro but in mobile devices its gone weird :(

Answer (score 1):

I suggest for you to use Twitter Bootstrap, you will facilitate your life. and make development as faster as possible.
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

Comment: Thanks alot bro I have downloaded that. Kindly fix the issue given above please as I already have crossed the deadline.

Answer (score 0):

There is some code you didn't post because you have responsive css for the navbar (which also has problems since you have a max-width for one at 800, and a min-width for one that is larger than 801, so you have a gap in the middle with no rules applied). To figure out how to make the rest of your site responsive, use your own navbar as an example once you fix that problem.

Comment: Thanks alot bro I have added a fiddle link which contain everything

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer would be, use **CSS3's media queries**.

***You can learn more about them here:***

1. http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries
2. http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem with a list of text and colored backgrounds (like boxes). The boxes/list items wouldn't line up properly in tablet size. It was just changing a border size from a `pt` to a `%`. That did the trick!

Comment: Looks like @Moussawi7 already gave this answer nine months ago!